# How to place instance of window in LayoutAnchorable AvalonDock 2

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I'm upgrading AvalonDock in a WPF C# application (not MVVM) from 1.3 to 2.0. In 1.3 I was able to place custom windows as long as used DockableContent:
XAML:

```
<!--<Window-->
<ad:DockableContent   x:Class="Test.JournalWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ad="clr-namespace:AvalonDock;assembly=AvalonDock" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

        Loaded="Journal_Loaded" StateChanged="Journal_StateChanged"
        Title="Journal" Icon = "Resources/journalLog.ico" HideOnClose="True" Height="300" Width="Auto">

    <ad:DockableContent.Resources>
      </ad:DockableContent.Resources>

                <Grid>  </Grid>
</ad:DockableContent>
<!--</Window>-->
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class JournalWindow : DockableContent
    {
        public JournalWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Code in MainWindow to display instantited element:

```
JournalWindow journalWindow;
 journalWindow = new JournalWindow()
            {
                Name = nameJournalWindow,
                Title = "Journal"
            };

            journalWindow.IsCloseable = true;
            journalWindow.HideOnClose = true;
            journalWindow.Show(dockManager);
```

How to place and show instance of JournalWindow in LayoutAnchorable or other layout element (previously as DockableContent) using AvalonDock 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AvalonDock is changed a lot with new version. In AD 2.0 you have two option:
1) The simplest one is to create a standard UserControl (in your case JournalWindow derived from UserControl instead of DockableContent) and put the control inside the LayoutAnchorable (as its Content). 
Sample code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.JournalWindow" ...>
...
</UserControl>

<LayoutAnchorable Title="My Journal Window">
   <testNamespace:JournalWindow/>
</LayoutAnchorable>
```

2) The recommended one is to use a MVVM approach and for this I'd point you to the sample project MVVMTestApp attached to AvalonDock library:
http://avalondock.codeplex.com/downloads/get/558780

Ado

Comment: If I will use JournalWindow as a control then is there any way to get from **it's** code behid i.e. 'bool isHidden = JournalWindow.IsHidden;' ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually deal with opening a new dialog on the fly as a floating pane.