# AvalonDock LayoutAnchorable doesnt show Control

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, avalondock, mahapps.metro

i have slightly the same problem like it was asked here befoere:
[How to place instance of window in LayoutAnchorable AvalonDock 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826634/how-to-place-instance-of-window-in-layoutanchorable-avalondock-2)

In this case, i am using AvalonDock 2.0, Caliburn.Micro and Mahapps.Metro.

It seems that i can actually map my viewmodel to 'LayoutAnchorable', but when i click on it, it doesnt show me the content of that control (it is a MetroContentControl). How should i put it...it looks like an invisible ContentControl that is being shown.

XAML-Code

```
<ad:LayoutRoot.BottomSide>
                    <ad:LayoutAnchorSide>
                        <ad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                            <ad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Test" ContentId="123">
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Controls:MetroContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveLogViewModel}"  />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ad:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </ad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                    </ad:LayoutAnchorSide>
                </ad:LayoutRoot.BottomSide>
```

Is there a limitation in AD 2.0 in using and placing controls? What is the best practice to do so?

*Update*

```
<ad:DockingManager x:Name="adManagerTop" DocumentsSource="{Binding DocumentSources}" Margin="0,0,0,40">
            <ad:DockingManager.Theme>
                <ad:MetroTheme />
            </ad:DockingManager.Theme>
            <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ad:LayoutItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CanFloat" Value="{Binding Model.CanFloat}" />
                </Style>
            </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
            <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Controls:MetroContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
            <ad:LayoutRoot>
                <ad:LayoutPanel>
                    <ad:LayoutDocumentPane />
                </ad:LayoutPanel>
            </ad:LayoutRoot>

    </ad:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just bind `AnchorablesSource` and `DocumentsSource` I did it like this in my app

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Shells/MainShellView.xaml

Then start the app and organize the panels like you want it to be when the user starts the program for the first time. Save the state to disk using the `XmlLayoutSerializer`, embed the XML as a resource inyour program. When you load the layout either use the layout on disc if one exists or use the one thats embedded in the program.

Comment: The idea of using a layout configuration file did not cross my mind yet. I will try to use that in the future. The problem is, if the Anchors are not hidden, the content of the control can be seen, but if its hidden, it doesnt.

Comment: its me again, i know now why. The MetroWindow has 'AllowTransparency' set to true. If i set it to false, this problem is gone and the embedded Webbrowser seems to work now too. Still, i will need a config for layout probably.